# Iteration multi-dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, glcm

I want to compute some operation (GLCM) over an image using a sliding window. The code to achieve it is:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops

from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

image = np.arange(36).reshape((6,6))

window = 5

result = np.zeros(image.shape)
for i in xrange(window/2,image.shape[0]-window/2):
    for j in xrange(window/2,image.shape[1]-window/2):
        sample = image[i-(window/2):i+(window/2)+1, j - (window/2):j+(window/2)+1]
        glcm = greycomatrix(sample, [1], [0], 256, symmetric=False, normed=True)
        result[i,j] = greycoprops(glcm, 'contrast')[0, 0]
```

It works but two for loops is very expensive. I want to increase the speed and so, looking around on the web, I tried to use the *as_stride* trick:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

image = np.arange(36).reshape((6,6))

window = 5

y = as_strided(image,shape=(image.shape[0] - window + 1,\
                            image.shape[1] - window + 1,) +\
               (window,window),  strides=image.strides * 2)
```

To compute, for e.g., the GLCM for the first window:

```
glcm = greycoprops(greycomatrix(y[0,0], [1], [0], 256, symmetric=False, normed=True))[0][0]
```

I tried to apply for all the sliding window as:

```
glcm[:,:] = greycoprops(greycomatrix(y[:,:], [1], [0], 256, symmetric=False, normed=True))[0][0]
```

But in this case, the `y[:,:]` doesn't have `ndim==2` as `y[0,0]` but `ndim==4`, and so . I can't find a way to iterate in a smart way over all the subset keeping the `ndim == 2` (required by the *greycomatrix* function).

**Edit**

I tried to use ravel and work over 1D vector and so, just 1 for-loop. This is the code:

```
a = y.ravel()
print a.shape
glcm=np.zeros(a.shape[0]/(window*window))
for i in np.arange(a.shape[0]/(window*window)):
    glcm[i] = greycoprops(greycomatrix(a[i*25:i*25+25].reshape(5,5), [1], [0], 256, symmetric=False, normed=True))[0][0]

result= glcm.reshape(y.shape[0],y.shape[1])
```

The processing time increase...

Answer (score 1):

Since you forgot to actually ask a question, I'm going to assume it was

> How do I make this run fast?

Well, in this case the harsh truth is, as good as python is going to get, doing a python `for` loop with a lot of slicing is always going to be relatively expensive compared to individual pixel operations.

So if speed is your concern here, you should implement some function in a language that allows you to get python bindings (eg. C with `cpython`), and use that function.

Answer (score 0):

With the `as_strided` `y` you still need to access the sub-arrays individually, for example:

```
for i in range(y.shape[0]):
    for j in range(y.shape[1]):
        sample = y[i,j,...]
        print sample
```

or even

```
for row in y:
    for sample in row:
        print sample
```

except that you need to collect the results.

In iterations like this, `as_strided` has a benefit only if it makes access to the subarrays more efficient.

But its real benefit comes if you can rewrite the GCLM calculation to work with a 4d arrays.  Some `numpy` operations are designed to operate on 1 or 2 of the axes, while the others just 'go along for the ride'.  For example, if your calculation simply consisted of taking the mean of the image.  With `y` that would simply be:

```
np.mean(y, axes=(-2,-1))
```